# Twitter SLComposeViewController Often Fails to Fire

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, twitter

I am having a strange issue with the Twitter SLComposeViewController. I now have an error in the imagePickerController method that says "sending void to parameter of incompatible type void (^)(void)"

I am also getting a warning where the twitter image is included "image selected from imagepicker" How do I actually get the image from the image picker? Thanks!!

**Here is the photo action:**

```
-(void) photoAction {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]
                                                          init];
    #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    #else
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    #endif
        imagePickerController.editing = YES;
        imagePickerController.delegate = (id)self;
        [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

**Here is the next method:**

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [[picker presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:[self showTweetSheet]];
     }
```

**And lastly the tweet method:**

```
-(void)showTweetSheet
{
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                           composeViewControllerForServiceType:
                                           SLServiceTypeTwitter];

    tweetSheet.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        switch(result) {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                break;
        }
    };

    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Text"];

     if (![tweetSheet addImage:@"image selected from imagepicker"]) {
         NSLog(@"Unable to add the image!");
     }

     if (![tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://twitter.com/"]]){
         NSLog(@"Unable to add the URL!");
     }

     [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:NO completion:^{
        NSLog(@"Tweet sheet has been presented.");
    }];
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the SlcomposeViewController code in separate method

```
-(void)showTweetSheet
 {
      SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = 
       [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter];

      tweetSheet.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
          switch(result) {
             case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                  break;
             case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                  break;
          }
      };

     [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Text];

     if (![tweetSheet addImage:image]) {
         NSLog(@"Unable to add the image!");
     }       

     if (![tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://twitter.com/"]]){
         NSLog(@"Unable to add the URL!");
     }

     [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:NO completion:^{
         NSLog(@"Tweet sheet has been presented.");
      }]; 
}
```

And when dismissing imagePickerController

```
[[picker presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self showTweetSheet]
}];
```

Also declare your image instance in .h file

```
UIImage *image;
```

Comment: Ok I am updating my question with the layout, I have an error and a warning now. I will explain in the update. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my question with my current code and the error message :) something about voids and parameters

Comment: check my updated answer, forgot to add some bunch of braces :)

Comment: Ok that fixes the error, I still have one warning that says unused variable in the line "UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];"

Comment: +1 for the great code on the completion handler. There is always a delay in the present view completing and the view being presented meaning that to add an activity indicator I had to use the switch statement. Thanks